# Google Apps Script - Retaining Slide Comments After Slide Update or Delete

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I'm working on a Google Apps Script which reads in rows of data from a Google Sheet, and creates a slide (It is basically a table on the slide which I populate with the data from the sheets).

The way my script currently works is:

1. Checks for any slides from the previous script execution and deletes them, except for the first slide. (This first slide is a template which I use to create copies of and populate data for each row in the sheet.)
2. Reads the first slide from the target Google Slide and creates a copy.
3. Replaces placeholder strings on the template's copy with data from the sheet row (This happens in a loop for each row).

As you can tell from this script, whenever I run the script after an update to the input Google Sheet, it kinda deletes and recreates everything. The problem with this approach is that if there are any comments added to the generated Google Slides deck, they are essentially wiped out.

From the UI, I can still see the comment history, but I'm not sure how I can access it and use it to restore slide comments back to the places where they originally were (or if it is even possible through the script APIs).

I've looked into some API documentation on [Comment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/comment) class which I think is for XmlService, and not Google Slides. I don't see anything under [Slides](https://developers.google.com/slides/api) documented for comments. Please let me know if there are some resources I can look into.

Based on my current script logic and/or availability of the APIs I'd need to extract-save-reapply comments, can this be done?

Comment: see this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650 probably it doesn't work in Slides too

Comment: Seems like it, @Kos. I think this is a feature waiting to be implemented since, like, 2012.